# Bitter tasting cider with Safale- 05

Tags: cider

I have a bitter tasting cider (think German beer) on my hands right now, and I really don't like the bitterness.

I started with an OG of 1.060, and my yeast was Safale 05.

Would aging help with getting rid of the bitter taste? how can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: How old is the cider now?  was it just apple juice and yeast?

Answer (score 2):

Aging may very well help.  The best ciders I've made hit their peak after a year or so.  But the "bitter" description surprises me.  I've never made a cider that I would call bitter.  Could it be sour?  Astringent?  Extremely dry?

Comment: All I can say is that it tasted a lot like a really bitter beer. So far, it has spent 3 weeks in the primary, 4 weeks in bottle. As for the recipe, it was just a simple juice, sugar, and yeast thing.

Comment: The give it time.  Taste one every month or so and see how it changes.